# Entire page markup is replaced on AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

When i call my function in my `js.erb` template it replaces the entire page rather than just the `div` that i indicate. Can anyone help?

**remove.js.erb**

```
$('div.mini-basket-wrapper').html("<%= j(render 'shop/baskorder/mini_basket') %>");


#This replaces the page completely
$('#basket-info').load(document.write(basket_text()));
```

**view**

```
<div id="basket-info">
  <div id="basket-amount">
    <div class='mini-basket-icon'>
     <%= image_tag 'shop/icons/basket.svg', alt: '' %>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      document.write(basket_text());
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    function fc_basket_text_from_cookie(empty_text, normal_text)
{
  var basket = readCookie('bk');

  if (basket)
  {
    var parts = decodeURIComponent(basket.replace(/\+/g, '%20')).split('|')

    if (parseInt(parts[1]) == 0)
      return normal_text.replace(/##VALUE##/g, parts[0]).replace(/##ITEMS##/g, parseInt(parts[1]));
      // return empty_text
    else
      return normal_text.replace(/##VALUE##/g, parts[0]).replace(/##ITEMS##/g, parseInt(parts[1]));
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

var emptyBasketHTML = "<span class='header_text'>Items in basket: 0 Total: &#163;0.00</span>";
function basket_text(){
  var populated = "<span class='header_text'>Items in basket: ##ITEMS##</span><span class='header_text'>Total: ##VALUE##</span>";
  //populated += "<input type='submit' value='Checkout' name='commit' class='go_botton header-checkout-button'>"
  return fc_basket_text_from_cookie(emptyBasketHTML,populated);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading here: [Using document.write](http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write).

> When the page finishes loading, the document becomes closed. An attempt to document.write in it will cause the contents to be erased.

Further the .load() function is used to load data from a server. I believe you want the .html function.

[Untested] Change the line `$('#basket-info').load(document.write(basket_text()));`

To `$('#basket-info').html(basket_text());`

Comment: Thanks @wnbates, so i've tried that and it doesn't do anything at all?

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: wouldn't know how to with js, and rails etc

Comment: This is not how to use load. It's supposed to load a file into an element : `$("#element").load("file.html")` or `file.txt` or `file.php`. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input. Realised what i was doing wrong and decided to add an ajax on success to my js file:

```
$(document).on('ajaxSuccess', function(){
    $('#basket-amount-info').html(basket_text());
});
```

Added this id `#basket-amount-info` to contain the script in the view.